# Flutter, open url when open scaffold

Tags: flutter

I am recently approaching flutter and I encounter this doubt / problem, I would like to transform this class that opens a link when submitting the `textfield` into a class that once opened opens that link directly. How can I do? I tried to remove the `onSubmitted()` but every time it gives me syntax errors.
Can anyone help me by guiding me in the resolution? I would just like to remove `onSubmitted()` and open that link when accessing the `EmptyTabState` class. Thanks for the help ^^

```
class _EmptyTabState extends State<EmptyTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: TextField(
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    openNewTab("http://example.com");
                  },
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openNewTab(value) {
    var browserModel = Provider.of<BrowserModel>(context, listen: false);
    browserModel.addTab(WebViewTab(
      key: GlobalKey(),
      webViewModel: WebViewModel(
          url: Uri.parse(value)
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call openNewTab method in the initState method:

```
class _EmptyTabState extends State<EmptyTab> {
 @override
  void initState() {
    onNewTab();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build
    ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I have another question, now it works with initState but when I open it anyway it opens the build widget and not the link. If I try to leave the scaffold blank, it leaves me a blank page. How can I do to allow openNewTab to display the site on the screen?

Comment: I added another reply to show another way okay.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package like flutter_inappwebview (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) and inside the body call like this, then you will not need the method openNewTab:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             Flexible(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: "http://example.com",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I can't use inappwebview because it doesn't allow me to do some operations. Isn't there an alternative way? like making a widget transparent?

Comment: What type of operations do you need? I've used this for a few things, not much elaborated.

Comment: I just need to open that link via that method. I just need an empty scaffold that recalls that method and that's it, I wouldn't want to use other solutions.

Comment: I don't knot how to do it without the package, but with the package you could set the initial url empty and set the url when click on the button and call to load I guess.